# R geom_tile width and height are ignored in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

The `height` and `width` parameters of `geom_tile` are not being taken into account when converted to `ggplotly`, as shown in the example below. Is there a work around? Please note that my dataset is in fact very large (+80k data points), so I would favor an efficient solution, if there is one.

```r
library(plotly)

X <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 1, 2), y = c(1, 1, 2, 2), z = 1:4)
gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z), width = .5, height = .5)

gg
ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in ggplotly. The easiest thing would be to convert your `geom_tile` to `geom_rect`. I don't think this will be any less efficient than `geom_tile`, since you are just replicating what `geom_tile` does internally.

```r
library(plotly)

X <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 1, 2), y = c(1, 1, 2, 2), z = 1:4)

width <- .5
height <- .5

gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x - width/2, xmax = x + width/2, 
                ymin = y - height/2, ymax = y + height/2, fill = z))

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]